# htaccess mod-rewrite to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following to redirect wildcard sub domains to corresponding folders:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !=www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/%1/$1/? [L]
```

I would like to add a rewrite rule that redirects anyone that accesses the direct /users/ path back to the sub-domain version like this:

```
www.domain.com/users/username/../../ => username.domain.com/../../
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)/?(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [QSA,NC,R,L]
```

Do you have other rules than the one listed on the question? if yes, put these before the other one.

eg:

```
http://www.domain.com/users/abc?q=test => http://abc.domain.com/?q=test
http://www.domain.com/users/abc/sub1/sub2 => http://abc.domain.com/sub1/sub2
http://www.domain.com/users/abc/sub1/?q=test => http://abc.domain.com/sub1/?q=test
```

Comment: Thank you! However this appears to only work for ../users/username => username.domain.com, I need it to also work for ../users/username/sub1/sub2/ => username.domain.com/sub1/sub2. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfect, any chance it can be made to work on both www.domain.com and domain.com versions?

Comment: I would recommend to redirect domain.com => www.domain.com (view my updated ansewr)