# How to .htaccess redirect files of certain type from root to subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf, redirect, subdirectory

A client had his PDF files uploaded to the CMS' root over month. I'ld like to move all PDFs into a new subfolder to keep the root clean. Problem now is they absolute linked these PDFs in many articles. Is there a way I can redirect all (and only) links to a root PDF to their new destination?

Additionally, I tried do my homeworks but couldn't find a comprehensive guide about .htaccess and ask you to share the best gem from you bookmarks.

Comment: So you want `domain.com/abc.pdf` => `domain.com/subfolder/abc.pdf`?

Comment: this post could be usefull for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597182/htaccess-mod-rewrite-to-subdomain

Comment: @anubhava - Exactly. But only for PDF in the root.

Comment: ok got it, posted an answer below for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.pdf)$ /subfolder/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one gives me a 500 Internal Server Error for the whole site

Comment: ah sorry, had a missing `(`, fixed it. Try now.

Comment: Now it works! From where do you know that stuff, man? From where do you learned it? I'ld like to learn it, too.

Comment: It is mostly due to my liking for regex and online Apache reference manual. It seems you didn't like my answer but there are many things that needed be corrected in other answer. 1. Adding `[L,NC,R=301]` flags 2. Escaping dot (otherwise in theory it can match `/abc_pdf` also 3. Correction of regex otherwise that regex matches URI such as `/Apdf`

Comment: I agree, the dot in my regex was matching anything and should have been escaped.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*?).pdf$ newpath/$1.pdf
```